# appCache event never fired in Chrome for HTML5

Tags: html

I am using HTML5 for a offline website. I write some code for event listener in a javascript file. But the events are never fired.

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;
if (appCache) {

    appCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function (event) {
        handleEvent(event);

    }, false);
    appCache.addEventListener('cached', function (event) {
        handleEvent(event);
    }, false);
    appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (event) {
        handleEvent(event);
    }, false);
    appCache.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
        handleEvent(event);
    }, false);

    appCache.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
        handleEvent(event);

    }, false);

}
else {
    console.log("Not Support");
};
```

The events can be fired in Firefox and IE, but cannot be fired in Chrome. It seems that in Chrome, firstly it will check the manifest version and then cache the resources in the manifest file, and secondly it will execute the js file. So the events have finished before the methods are registed. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually check the `window.applicationCache.status` variable the first time your script is loaded, and then rely on the event listeners after that.